# TSearch2 - dots explosion

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

Following conversion

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'Google.com');
```

returns this:

```
'google.com':1
```

Why does [TSearch2](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/V2/) engine didn't return something like this?

```
'google':2, 'com':1
```

Or how can i make the engine to return the exploded string as i wrote above?
I just need "Google.com" to be foundable by "google".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no quick and easy solution.

Denis is correct in that the parser is recognizing it as a hostname, which is why it doesn't break it up.

There are 3 other things you can do, off the top of my head.

1. You can disable the host parsing in the database. See [postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch-configuration.html) for details. E.g. something like `ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION your_parser_config
   DROP MAPPING FOR url, url_path`
2. You can write your own custom dictionary.
3. You can pre-parse your data before it's inserted into the database in some manner (maybe splitting all domains before going into the database).

---

I had a similar issue to you last year and opted for solution (2), above.

My solution was to write a custom dictionary that splits words up on non-word characters. A custom dictionary is a lot easier & quicker to write than a new parser. You still have to write C tho :)

The dictionary I wrote would return something like `'www.facebook.com':4, 'com':3, 'facebook':2, 'www':1'` for the 'www.facebook.com' domain (we had a unique-ish scenario, hence the 4 results instead of 3).

The trouble with a custom dictionary is that you will no longer get stemming (ie: www.books.com will come out as www, books and com). I believe there is some work (which may have been completed) to allow chaining of dictionaries which would solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First off in case you're not aware, tsearch2 is deprecated in favor of the built-in functionality:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9/static/textsearch.html

As for your actual question, google.com gets recognized as a host by the parser:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch-parsers.html

If you don't want this to occur, you'll need to pre-process your text accordingly (or use a custom parser).

Comment: it is actually still tsearch2. It's just built into postgresql.